# How to save UIWebView content into photo library

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How to save UIWebView Content into photo Library

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{

    UIImage* image = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.frame.size);
    {
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (image != nil) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self, nil, nil);
    }

}
```

This code is saving empty page.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.webView.bounds.size);
 
 [self.webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);  ITs working with this code....

Comment: but its giving warning renderInContext is not found

Answer (score 1):

I've released an app ([Web2Pic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mammoth-web2pic-webpage-full/id450749975?mt=8)) doing that, and please trust me that ***UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.frame.size);*** 
can do nothing except getting a small image from the visible area in our UIWebView ;-(

The right way is a bit complex but it just works:

1.Use **JavaScript** in our UIWebView to get these float values:

```
   //Whole page size in HTML coordinate
   document.body.scrollWidth
   document.body.scrollHeight
   //UIWebView visible size in HTML coordinate
   window.innerWidth
   window.innerHeight
```

2.Now we can 'cut' the whole page into dozens of UIWebView-sized small pieces. Then we can capture every small pieces individually and save them into our Cache. I implemented this by calculating page-offsets and use **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.frame.size);** to get a array of images. In addition, you should cache the image array into the file system, or the app will eventually crash!

3.When we finally got all the small pieces, we can start a full-resolution context: **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(document.body.scrollWidth,document.body.scrollHeight));**

4.Render every small images into the big context based on the coordinates. And **be careful to the corners**, the last image in every line/row may not be a full image.

5.There is still one step left: saving the big image. **Do not save it into the PhotoAlbum**, because iOS will automatically cut down the resolution of images in the album. Instead, we can save it into the file system and enable the app's **iTunes File Share** support, or even write a simple in-app photo manager.

Hope these can help ;-)

Yichao Peak Ji

Comment: Can u Plz Guide me because after using your approach the image which is saved into my photo album is white image(blank image) don't know why ???