# Save Image From UIWebView into Photo Library in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to save image from UIWebView into Photo Library in iOS app.

I also read [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766671/how-to-saving-uiwebview-content-into-photo-library][1]

But i can't save.
i wrote following codes in save method.

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender
{
    NSString *sizeOfImageByJs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"
                                 "document.body.scrollHeight;"
                                 "window.innerWidth;"
                                 "window.innterHeight;"];


    NSString *urlToSave = [webViewOfPhoto stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:sizeOfImageByJs];

    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSave];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
}
```

It's doesn't save anythings.
How to save it?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the view gets downloaded? Is image or imageData nil?

Comment: Set a breakpoint or temporarily add `NSLog(@"%@", image);` after the image to just see the value of the image. You can also write `if (!image) { /* show some appropriate message here */ }` to programmatically see if the image was created

Comment: Yes! It's say NULL. What's wronging in my codes?

Comment: Print out the value of "urlToSave" and try pasting that into your web browser and see what happens. It seems most likely that something is wrong with the url to the image